# How to get values from params.php in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii2 for my application. In `params.php` file I have defined an array like:

```
return ['setValue'=>100];
```

And I have `include params.php` in `web.php`:

```
<?php
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$config = [
    'params' => $params,
];
return $config;
```

And I am using another file `header.php` in views folder. So how can I get params array in `header.php`? I have used like `\Yii::$app->params;`, but
it is not working.

Answer (score 23):

Be sure you have a proper config/main.php  (this is a sample for a backend application using advanced template)

```
  <?php
    $params = array_merge(
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
    );

    return [
        'id' => 'your-app-backend',
        'name' => 'Your APP Backend',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
        'modules' => [],
        'components' => [
            'log' => [
                'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
                'targets' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                        'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'errorHandler' => [
                'errorAction' => 'site/error',
            ],
        ],
        'params' => $params,
    ];
```

Assuming you have a param.php with

```
<?php
  return [
    'adminEmail' => 'my_mail@example.com',
 ];
```

you can get the param using yii::$app->params

```
Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'];
```

for printing use

```
echo Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'];
```

Comment: @shanthiJagadeesh   answer  updated  with advanced  template main.php

Answer (score 7):

You can access to one value with:

```html
$value = Yii::$app->params['nameParameter'];
```

But, If you want to get the array

```
$values = Yii::$app->params;
```

You should be able to access all the properties defined in your config file which are integrated for use as "Yii::$app" attributes. In this case In this case the "params" attribute. :

According to the documentation  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html